# Calling a Method with Jest in Vue Testing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

Let's say I have a very basic form with a date-picker and a button that gets the date value from the date-picker (like in the example code below).

How do I unit test `setDateFromInput` with a parameter?

*SetDate.vue:*

```html
<template>
    <form>
        <!-- date-picker -->
        <input name="selected-date" ref="mySelectedDate">

        <!-- display Selected date-->
        <div ref="showdate" v-html="daytime"></div>

        <button @click="setDateFromInput">Set Date</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            daytime: this.setDateFromInput()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setDateFromInput: function() {
            return this.$refs.mySelectedDate.value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*SetDate.spec.js:*

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SetDate from '@/components/SetDate.vue'

describe('SetDate.vue', () => {
  it('sets date', () => {
      // ?????
      const wrapper =  mount(SetDate, {
          propsData: {
          }
      })
  })
});
```

I've seen a couple other similar questions, but they seemed a bit more involved than I need or didn't follow Vue documentation.

Comment: @mayakwd - not a duplicate as indicated above. Different issues.

Comment: @SteveV Can you clarify what you mean by `didn't follow Vue documentation`?